# How to check in Eloquent query if an item is between certain dates?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to bring an array of current items, in the sense that the item has a start_Date and an end_Date, I want to check if today's date is in between those two and if it is then I want it to be send to the view.

This is the current query that brings all the items that are created by the logged in user

```
$user = auth()->user()->id;
$survey_created = Survey::with('evaluation')->where('user_id', $user)
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

The survey table is like this, the survey table is linked to the evaluations table, this is where the dates are

```
Schema::create('surveys', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->longText('description');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->boolean('anonymous');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});

Schema::create('evaluations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('survey_id')->unsigned();
    $table->dateTime('init_date');
    $table->dateTime('end_date');
    $table->dateTime('report_date');
    $table->foreign('survey_id')->references('id')->on('surveys');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I have the current date and time

```
$now = Carbon::now();
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following

```
$user = auth()->user()->id;
$now = Carbon::now();
$survey_created = Survey::with('evaluation')
    ->where('user_id', $user)
    ->whereHas('evaluation', function ($query) use ($now){
        $query->whereDate('init_date', '<=', $now);
        $query->whereDate('end_date', '>', $now);
    })
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

You can use whereHas and whereDate function.